# ptrace suid process (after it drops previlege)

Tags: linux, memory, process, ptrace, suid

I understand that we cannot do ptrace on suid binaries. However, I'm wondering why we cannot do ptrace after the binary drops its previlege to uid instead of euid.

For example, in the binary the suid binary drops privilege after some steps.

```
 seteuid (euid); /* euid was obtained by geteuid() */
 ret_chdir = chdir (path);
 seteuid (ruid); /* ruid was obtained by getuid() */

 system("whoami");
 printf("Enter any char");
 scanf("%c", &junk);
```

In my case when "whoami" is printed, it is the user name of the process but not the owner of the process. When the program is waiting for a junk input, I was trying to attach to the running process with the uid as the user name, but it failed even though the binary had dropped the privilege. Is it possible that ptrace attach uses the saved-uid state to decide that I'm not the owner?

Comment: This might be a better question for unix.stackexchange.com. It's more a question about the Unix design, not actual programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your [yama ptrace scope](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) is probably preventing you from attaching to the process. In essence, most Linux kernels today default to not allowing attaching to arbitrary processes.

A process can ask to be traced by its parent (`ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)`), but if you want to use `PTRACE_ATTACH`, you either need that process to specify, using `prctl`, that it wants your process to attach to it, or the yama scope need to be set to 0 (or, your process can run as root, of course).